# Flex/Bison not evaluating properly

Tags: c++, c, bison, flex-lexer

For some reason or another, bison doesn't want to do any evaluation. Compilation of all files goes smoothly and the program runs. When I enter the expression `4+5` and press return, it creates tokens for `4` `+` `5` respectively. I can even put in some `printf` into the places where bison recognizes the attributes of each token including the plus (43).

However the program never evaluates this production `expr '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }`. It's simply never called at least to my knowledge and even if it was this production `assign '\n' { printf("%d\n", $1); }` never prints out the value. Upon `^D` to quit, it fires `void yyerror(const char *)`.

Any help on this matter is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
//FLEX
%{
    //#include <stdio.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
%}

%option noyywrap

letter  [A-Za-z]
digit   [0-9]
space   [ \t]

var     {letter}
int     {digit}+
ws      {space}+

%%

{var}   { yylval = (int)yytext[0]; return VAR; }
{int}   { yylval = atoi(yytext); return CONST; }
{ws}    { }
.       { return (int)yytext[0]; }

%%

/* nothing */
```

.

```
//BISON
%{

//INCLUDE
//#include <ctype.h>

//DEFINE
#define YYDEBUG 1

//PROTOTYPE
void yyerror(const char *);
void print_welcome();
int get_val(int);
void set_val(int, int);

%}

%token CONST
%token VAR

%%

session
    : { print_welcome(); }
      eval
    ;

eval
    : eval line
    |
    ;

line
    : assign '\n'       { printf("%d\n", $1); }
    ;

assign
    : VAR '=' expr      { set_val($1, $3); $$ = $3; }
    | expr              { $$ = $1; }
    ;

expr
    : expr '+' term     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '-' term     { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | term              { $$ = $1; }
    ;

term
    : term '*' factor   { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | term '/' factor   { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | term '%' factor   { $$ = $1 % $3; }
    | factor            { $$ = $1; }
    ;

factor
    : '(' expr ')'      { $$ = $2; }
    | CONST             { $$ = $1; }
    | VAR               { $$ = get_val($1); }
    ;

%%

void yyerror(const char * s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

void print_welcome()
{
    printf("Welcome to the Simple Expression Evaluator.\n");
    printf("Enter one expression per line, end with ^D\n\n");
}

static int val_tab[26];

int get_val(int var)
{
    return val_tab[var - 'A'];
}

void set_val(int var, int val)
{
    val_tab[var - 'A'] = val;
}
```

.

```
//MAIN

//PROTOTYPE
int yyparse();

int main()
{
    extern int yydebug;
    yydebug = 0;
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on YACC debugging by compiling with -DYYDEBUG=1 and then setting shell env variable export YYDEBUG=1 before running the program.  It prints very readable output about shift and reduce operations.

Comment: Does the lexer return the '\n'?  If not, then your line rule will not fire.  You might count '\n' as white space and use ';' as the end of an expression.

Comment: You do not need the term and factor rules.  Just use "expr : expr '+' expr" and use the YACC operator precedence mechanism.

Comment: Your lexer allow a variable to be upper or lower case, but val_tab[] only supports upper case.

Comment: @brianbeuning The debug output, might have been helpful to add to this post, but I forgot to add it last night. Not handling \n was part of my problem, see post below. Also, I'm using expr and factor because it is a school sample I did not feel like changing it. I have my own project to build now. Lastly, `val_tab[]` only handled uppercase, in the sample. For completeness I should go in and add `toupper()` on my var lex code. But since this is a sample, I just didn't add that in. Thanks for all your advice, I will definitely use it going forward with my own project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `lex` file does not have any rule which matches `\n`, because in `lex`/`flex`, `.` matches any character *except* line-end. The default rule for `lex` (or `flex`) echoes and otherwise ignores the matched character, so that's what happens to the `\n`. Since the parser won't be able to accept a `line` unless it sees a `\n` token, it will eventually be forced to present you with a syntax error.

So you need to change the rule

```
.     { return (int)yytext[0]; }
```

to

```
.|\n  { return (int)yytext[0]; }
```

(I wouldn't have bothered with the cast to `int` but it's certainly not doing any harm, so I left it in.)

Comment: What's funny is I shutdown, and went to sleep for the night. Then I had a dream that this was the problem (thank you suby). I laughed so hard when I saw your post this morning, I can be a real idiot sometimes. Thanks for your help, I greatly appreciate it. Everything works fine now. :D